# Regular Expression for <.5 to >15.900

Tags: javascript, regex

i m new in RE. I want a regular expression which tells a between condition of .5 to 15.900.

can i make two condition one is less then .5 and other one is greater then 15.900

Comment: Could you expound, whats the context? Show what you've tried?

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if a number is greater than `.5` and smaller than `15.9`? Then you don't need regex. And if it's not that please clarify.

Comment: i have this ^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]{0,3} for accepting 3 decimal values.

Comment: yes oriol you are write . i used validation engine so that i hv to use only regular expression.

Comment: Misuse of regular expression. Use math.

Comment: You wouldn't use a a regex for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: i know its very hard to use, but my validation engine plugin only use regular expression how can change this.

Comment: try this http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range

Comment: That tool doesn't work. This isn't something you'd do with regexs. https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Regular_expression http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: ok chris. can i make two condition one is less then .5 and other one is greater then 15.900

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex is not a proper way of comparing numbers.

However, if you still want to do it, you can split the interval `(.5, 15.9)` in subintervals:

- `(.5, .6)`: `^0*\.5\d+$`
- `[.6, 1)`: `^0*\.[6-9]\d*$`
- `[1, 10)`: `^0*[1-9](?:\.\d+)?$`
- `[1, 10)`: `^0*[1-9](?:\.\d+)?$`
- `[10, 15)`: `^0*1[0-4](?:\.\d+)?$`
- `[15, 15.9)`: `^0*15(?:\.[0-8]\d*)?$`

And then join them:

```js
/^0*\.5\d+$|^0*\.[6-9]\d*$|^0*[1-9](?:\.\d+)?$|^0*[1-9](?:\.\d+)?$|^0*1[0-4](?:\.\d+)?$|^0*15(?:\.[0-8]\d*)?$/
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bL7hA1/1)